# Puzzle about grouping similar rows which differ by occasional missing values

Tags: mysql

I've encountered a really interesting problem when dealing with rows which should be similar, but differ between each other by one or more missing values. What I would like to do is perform a query which would collapse (group) all similar rows into one entry that contains values for all (or as many as possible) columns, in order to remove the missing values.

I will split this problem into the two subproblems below:

Problem A)

Given the table:

```
|--------------------------|
|  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
|--------------------------|
|   a    |        |   c    |
|   a    |   b    |        |
|        |        |   c    |
|   a    |   b    |        |
|        |   b    |   c    |
|   a    |        |   c    |
|--------------------------|
```

Create a query which returns 
-> (a, b, c)

Problem B)

Given the table:

```
|--------------------------|
|  col1  |  col2  |  col3  |
|--------------------------|
|   a    |        |   c    |
|   a    |   b    |        |
|        |        |   c    |
|   a    |   b    |        |
|        |   b    |   c    |
|   a    |        |   c    |
|   d    |        |   f    |
|   d    |        |        |
|        |   e    |   f    |
|   d    |   e    |        |
|   d    |        |   f    |
|--------------------------|
```

Create a query which returns
-> (a, b, c), (d, e, f)

Any ideas or hints on how any of this could be achieved?

Comment: A 3-tuple, like `(a, b, c)` exists as long as `a` is related to `b`, `b` is related to `c` **and** `a` is related to `c`. Is this correct?

Comment: Why not {d,e,c} ?

Comment: @JeffUK `e` is not related to `c`, neither is `d` to `c`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I view this as a sort of inspired homework problem.  If you recognize that `col1` can form the groups for the other two columns, there is a simple query.

Comment: It's not homework. This is an actual production pipeline.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos nothing in the question about relationships.  I would say that {'d','e',''} and {'','','c} "differ between each other by one or more missing values"

Comment: My actual production database has 7 of these columns and will contain 20 columns in the future. Each row has at most 2-3 missing values. I don't have the relation between a,b,c or d,e,f. Instead, I am trying to build this relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grouping on the `col1` column and then selecting the `MAX()` of the other two columns.  If you look closely at the first table, you will see that the only values which `col2` and `col3` have are `b` and `c`, respectively.  The same reasoning applies for your second table, which however has two distinct values for `col1`.

```
SELECT
    col1, MAX(col2) AS col2, MAX(col3) AS col3
FROM yourTable
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY col1
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to repeat this iteratively over each column and then extract the unique occurences from each query result?

Comment: @AlexChi I don't understand your question.  What else do you need besides this query?  Update your question.

Comment: I need to repeat this query for each column. First I would group by col1, then group by col2, then by col3 and so on. Of course, the outputs from these queries will greatly overlap, so I need to discard repeating occurences. What is the optimal way to perform this?

Comment: There are no overlaps from what I can see.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: When I group by col1, I get a different set of results than when grouping by col2 (or col3 for that matter). About 90% of the results overlap, because of the grouping criteria.

Comment: SQL is a declaritive language.  You tell it what the relationships are and then maybe it returns some data.  If you want to find unknown relationships in your data, then machine learning might be what you actually need.

Comment: I am applying machine learning unto the results. This is just for pre-processing and automatic labeling.

Comment: Something like k-means or another clustering technique might be useful here.  By dumb luck, my query appears to work; maybe it fails for your larger data set.  You could try rotating the columns in my query, e.g. to see if one column can form unique clusters with the other two columns.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Really appreciative of your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If a 3-tuple exists as long as `col1` is related to `col2`, `col1` is related to `col3` **and** `col2` is related to `col3`, then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
FROM mytable AS t1
-- col1 is realted to col2
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t2.col2 IS NOT NULL
-- col1 is related to col3
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 ON t1.col1 = t3.col1 AND t3.col3 IS NOT NULL
WHERE t1.col1 IS NOT NULL 
      -- col2 is related to col3
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable AS t4
                  WHERE t4.col2 = t2.col2 AND t4.col3 = t3.col3);
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/WHB20766)

Comment: Thank you! Trying to scale this example to my production data now :)